# How many 1-regular graphs can be produced by deleting edges from a even complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a complete graph $K_n$ where $n > 1$ and $n$ is even, how many distinct 1-regular graphs can be produced by only deleting edges?

By "distinct" I mean the vertices are numbered or taken based on the adjacency matrix.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What does a 1-regular graph look like?

Comment: A 1-regular graph looks like a set of disconnected edges. I am stumped.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at some small cases, say $n = 1$ through $5$ or $6$, and see if anything comes to mind.

Comment: That's a good start...only in the $n$ even cases can you get any $1$-regular graphs at all.

Comment: Because every vertex is connected initially, an even complete graph can be reduced to $1$-regular because it can be split into a set of vertex pairs. When $n$ is odd, it cannot be split into pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: For $n$ even: Say the vertices are $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$.

Pick a vertex to be joined to $v_1$ by an edge.

Find the lowest numbered unused vertex, and pick a different unused vertex to be joined by an edge.

Etc.

The correct anaswer is $\frac{n!}{(2^{\frac{n}{2}}) (\frac{n}{2})!}$

Comment: For $n$ vertices, there is an initial $c = n - 1$ choices. Then there are $ c = n - 2$ choices. When $c = 2$ we terminate. So I'm getting for $K_n$ there are $n!$ distinct $1$-regular graphs?

Comment: Not quite.  For the first step there are $n-1$ choices, as you say.  But for the next step there are $n-3$ choices (you can't use either of the first two vertices you picked, nor can you pair the current vertex with itself).

Comment: Thanks. So for any even $n$, you take the odd numbers $n - 1$ through $1$. $n - 1$ will be the $\frac{n}{2}$th odd number. To sum the first $m$ odd numbers you take $m^2$. So the answer on $n$ vertices is $(\frac{n}{2})^2$.

Comment: Not $(\frac{n}{2})^2$.  Look at what happens for instance if $n=8$.  Then the number of graphs is $7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1=105$.

Comment: I get $\frac{n!}{(2^{\frac{n}{2}}) (\frac{n}{2})!}$. Should I answer this question myself?